# jQuery "Attribute Starts With Selector" not working in iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, selector

I have an iFrame. All its elements are loaded. Anyway, I am not able to select elements using jQuery selector by "part" of the id/class/etc.

This is my code:

```
//Not working
$('#iFrameID').contents().find($('[id^="lodingImg"]')));

//Works 
$('[id^="lodingImg"]'))
```

Dos anyone knew if this type of jQuery selectors do not works in the iFrame. I have recently read that .live is not working in iframe, too. So, my questions is if I am doing something wrong or this is limitation of the library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should work just fine, but there's a parenthesis too many on both examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will quite happily take a selector as a **string**, there's no reason to wrap that selector in a call to the jQuery function. And, in fact, there's probably a reason **not** to do so, since I suspect that's what's causing your code not to work.

This code:

```
$('#iFrameID').contents().find($('[id^="lodingImg"]'));
```

will look for elements in `$('#iFrameID').contents()` that match the elements found by `$('[id^="lodingImg"]')` - which will be run on the parent window calling the Javascript, not the `<iframe>` element, and likely return zero elements.

Simply call:

```
$('#iFrameID').contents().find('[id^="lodingImg"]');
```

instead.